# IE9 Empty Text Node

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I'm building a site under PHP and it shows up well in Chrome, Firefox, IE7,8,9. The problem is when I analyse the source code in IE9 (with IE9 standards) it is full of empty text nodes(every element has an empty node text right after closing).
Is it because I'm using PHP includes? For instance `index.php` include the `header.php` and `footer.php`...
The files encoding is UTF-8 No Mark but I tried different ones...

[image: Empty text Nodes]

Comment: Please post code sample and provide additional information. We can't help you without looking at the code.

Comment: Have you had a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379380/ie7-cause-of-text-empty-text-node

Comment: If you check any other code, don't you see these empty text nodes too? )

Comment: Have you validated your HTML? It's a small thing, but it goes a long way in resolving issues like this.

Comment: Hello Kent. This happens with every element (even <head> ones )

Comment: Iota, i have checked in w3 and it gives 2 errors (images without alt)

Comment: What `DOCTYPE` are you using?

Comment: Well you could use `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` . not that the DOCTYPE is the cause of the issue(?) but its a good practice to stick to one.. Reference: [transitional-vs-strict-markup](http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup/)

Comment: DiogoMendonça- It would be great if you could attach an image of the text-nodes you are seeing. I see @Marat has posted below its quite normal..

Comment: I provided a link on my post http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/22/emptyf.png.. although it is Portuguese, you can see the empty nodes after each element. Thanks for your time

Comment: Noticed this myself after converting a legacy web app from IE quirks to standards. Non-issue as the answer states. In fact viewing this SO page in IE developer tools shows same behavior. You can remove carriage returns and strip whitespace between elements if removing it is necessary (but doesn't really hurt anything.. except for sending some extra bytes).

Answer (score 3):

Text nodes between elements are not empty. They just contain whitespace (typically space, line feed, and tab characters). It's perfectly fine.

Comment: But there's something wrong with my code? It only happens in IE9 standards

Comment: Actually, it happens in all browsers as per [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/content-models.html#content-models): "The space characters are always allowed between elements. User agents represent these characters between elements in the source markup as text nodes in the DOM." There is nothing _problematic_ with this.

Comment: You're likely noticing it as F12 (IE debugger) looks like it shows the DOM as a tree (which is more *correct* but not as user friendly sometimes). You will likely see the same if you open Opera Dragonfly in Opera and switch to view the DOM as a tree. Do this by right clicking on the DOM view and selecting the first option from the context menu.